# Who is this Batman villain that appears in the book "Batman is Brave!"?

Tags: dc, batman, character-identification

In the book [Batman is Brave!](https://books.google.fi/books?id=MsdyE-wgGmkC) there is this page:

[image: Batman villains]

I know The Riddler, Poison Ivy, The Joker, and Catwoman, but who's the big guy?? He is at least as big as Bane, but he's missing the mask. He also reminds me of Sandman, but Sandman is from the Marvel universe...

Comment: FYI: There was a character called Sandman in the 1960's TV series, check out http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/The_Sandman

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's [Clayface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clayface), one of Batman's most persistent enemies dating back to the 1950s. The name has been used by several different versions of the same character over the years, but in this instance it's probably [Matt Hagen](http://dcau.wikia.com/wiki/Clayface).

[image]

If you want more info, the author of your book (Donald Lemke) wrote another one that might be of some help to you; "[Who is Clayface?](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/batman-classic-who-is-clayface/id569217843?mt=11)"

[image]